# Does Google-managed SSL certificate use same keypair at renewal?

Tags: ssl-certificate, google-kubernetes-engine

In Google Kubernetes Engine, it's possible to set up a ["Google-managed SSL certificate"](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs).  Obviously, before a certificate expires, Google needs to get a new one.  When Google does this, does it use the same keypair, or does it generate a new keypair?

The reason for this question is that I may need to allow "certificate pinning" against an SSL certificate.  This won't work if the keypair changes at every renewal.

Answer (score 1):

Public document for Google managed SSL certificate renewal is available [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates#google-managed_ssl_certificate_renewal). But for information about same keypair, you may need to contact GCP support.